# to call yepnope once or many times?

Tags: javascript, yepnope

The `yepnope.js` provides its useful API: `yepnope`. It accepts a single object or an array as its parameter.

But are

```
yepnope({
  load: 'a.js',
  complete: function() {
    console.log("loaded a.js");
  },
});

yepnope({
  load: 'b.js',
  complete: function() {
    console.log("loaded b.js");
  },
});
```

and

```
yepnope([
{
  load: 'a.js',
  complete: function() {
    console.log("loaded a.js");
  },
},
{
  load: 'b.js',
  complete: function() {
    console.log("loaded b.js");
  },
}
]);
```

equivalent? If not, which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, I don't think there's a difference. It's up to your style, the situation, and how the rest of the application is written.

When these two examples are run in Chrome, the developer tools show just about the same page load times. On average, it looks like the first example is a few milliseconds faster. But sometimes it can be slower, too.